# Iterate dict Ansible, each key multiple values

Tags: loops, dictionary, ansible

I have a dict like this:

```
  distr:
    Alice:
    - Avocado
    - Cherries
    Bob:
    - Apple
    David:
    - Pineapple
    - Watermelon
    John:
    - Banana
    - Mango
    Shara:
    - Orange
    - Peach
```

Now I want to execute a task with each combination.

Like this:

```
Alice eats Avocado
Alice eats Cherries
Bob eats Apple
David eats Pineapple
David eats Watermelon
...
```

My ansible is like that:

```
- name: Debug
  debug:
    msg: {{ item.key }} eats {{ item }}
  with_items: "{{ lookup('dict', distr) }}"
```

The result:

```
TASK [Debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'Alice ', 'value': ['Avocado', 'Cherries']}) => {
    "msg": "Alice eats ['Avocado', 'Cherries']"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'Bob ', 'value': ['Apple']}) => {
    "msg": "Bob eats ['Apple']"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'David ', 'value': ['Pineapple', 'Watermelon']}) => {
    "msg": "David eats ['Pineapple', 'Watermelon']"
}
```

I tried with subelements and other type of loops without luck. I think this is really simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'll need to process your data to get it into a more useful structure. We want a flat list consisting of `(person, food)` tuples, and we can get there using the `product` filter, which returns the cross product of two lists. For example, the expression `["Alice"]|product(["Avocado", "Cherries"])` evalutes to `[["Alice", "Avocado"], ["Alice", "Cherries"]]`.

We can use a looping `set_fact` task to create our list:

```
- set_fact:
    cross: "{{ cross + [item[0]]|product(item[1])|list }}"
  loop: "{{ distr.items()|list }}"
  vars:
    cross: []
```

The above tasks iterates through each `(key, values)` tuple of your
dictionary and appends the cross product of the key and values to a
new list, `cross`.  The result looks like this:

```
"cross": [
    [
        "Alice",
        "Avocado"
    ],
    [
        "Alice",
        "Cherries"
    ],
    [
        "Bob",
        "Apple"
    ],
    [
        "David",
        "Pineapple"
    ],
    [
        "David",
        "Watermelon"
    ],
    [
        "John",
        "Banana"
    ],
    [
        "John",
        "Mango"
    ],
    [
        "Shara",
        "Orange"
    ],
    [
        "Shara",
        "Peach"
    ]
]
```

Putting that all together, we get:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    distr:
      Alice:
        - Avocado
        - Cherries
      Bob:
        - Apple
      David:
        - Pineapple
        - Watermelon
      John:
        - Banana
        - Mango
      Shara:
        - Orange
        - Peach

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        cross: "{{ cross + [item[0]]|product(item[1])|list }}"
      loop: "{{ distr.items()|list }}"
      vars:
        cross: []

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item[0] }} eats {{ item[1] }}"
      loop: "{{ cross }}"
```

And the output of running the above playbook is:

```
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['Alice', ['Avocado', 'Cherries']])
ok: [localhost] => (item=['Bob', ['Apple']])
ok: [localhost] => (item=['David', ['Pineapple', 'Watermelon']])
ok: [localhost] => (item=['John', ['Banana', 'Mango']])
ok: [localhost] => (item=['Shara', ['Orange', 'Peach']])

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['Alice', 'Avocado']) => {
    "msg": "Alice eats Avocado"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['Alice', 'Cherries']) => {
    "msg": "Alice eats Cherries"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['Bob', 'Apple']) => {
    "msg": "Bob eats Apple"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['David', 'Pineapple']) => {
    "msg": "David eats Pineapple"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['David', 'Watermelon']) => {
    "msg": "David eats Watermelon"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['John', 'Banana']) => {
    "msg": "John eats Banana"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['John', 'Mango']) => {
    "msg": "John eats Mango"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['Shara', 'Orange']) => {
    "msg": "Shara eats Orange"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['Shara', 'Peach']) => {
    "msg": "Shara eats Peach"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Work perfect!
Thanks a lot!